# how to apply deep-learning for UI test automation?

Tags: testing, automation, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

Deep-learning is applied to play game in some projects, so it should make sense to apply it for UI test automation. Any comments on this idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In large software, it is really hard and time taking to test out all possible scenarios via traditional approach. So, building a machine learning model to do this is a neat idea. The end goal for such a system would be to crash to make the software unresponsive.

There is research being done on this idea. You should take a look at [this research paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d2ae/393cf723228cf6f96d61ee068c681203e943.pdf) which explores Reinforcement Learning as an approach to automated GUI robustness testing. Reinforcement Learning is also one of the approaches used in teaching computers to play games.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just went through the papaer(A Reinforcement Learning Approach to Automated GUI Robustness Testing),  will look into Q-learning algorithm and update this question.

Comment: Read the paper, ran into this statement "However, tests that aim at critical faults, like crashes and
excessive response times, are completely automatable and can be very
effective." Stopped reading the paper as these people clearly have no idea that testing is done in context. They just tried to remove the context. That's not testing, that's clicking stuff and hoping for the software to break.